# np.maximum.accumulate with nan values

Tags: numpy

It seems the `np.maximum.accumulate` function does not handle nan well.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,np.nan,3,1])
np.maximum.accumulate(arr)
```

gives all nans after 2nd element.

How to get the result `[1,np.nan,3,3]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.fmax.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fmax.html#numpy.fmax), which ignores `nan`s:

```
arr = np.array([1,np.nan,3,1])

np.fmax.accumulate(arr)
# array([1., 1., 3., 3.])
```

If you need to keep the `nan`s:

```
np.where(np.isnan(arr), np.nan, np.fmax.accumulate(arr))
# array([ 1., nan,  3.,  3.])
```